# Google maps not displaying description of markers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to display title/description on click of markers. Markers are getting displayed but on click description not getting displayed. I saw in console log error message is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined on line no 40", i dont know whats wrong with my code, can anyone help me?

```js
   var locations = [
      ['Asia','Asia'],
      ['America','America'],
      ['India','India']
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 1,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
     var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+locations[i][1]+'&sensor=false';
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            var p = data.results[0].geometry.location;
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map
            }); 

         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
          })(marker, i));
       });
    }
```

```css
#map{
   height:400px;
   width:500px; 
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>

<
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand why its not working we need to understand how closure work.

The closure has access to its own scope (variables defined between its curly brackets), has access to the outer function’s variables, and access to the global variables.

Important to note is that Closures have access to the outer function’s variable even after the outer function returns and it store reference to actual variable.

Now in case of your code , **for loops** in JavaScript have no scope and variable is declared only once.

Now important is that asynchronous code can't run untill all synchronous code finishes. So when the getJSON callbacks run, because they have a closure over the same variable i, they all use the current value of i because the callbacks run after the loop has completely finished creating the callbacks

Now to fix this we can put a new function to run with its own scope so that in callbacks inside loop, there is a new closure over each different value.

Here is the updated code. Modified getJSON part and added required closure.

```js
   var locations = [
      ['Asia','Asia'],
      ['America','America'],
      ['India','India']
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 1,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
     var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+locations[i][1]+'&sensor=false';
        $.getJSON(url, (function (i) {
             return function(data) {
                var p = data.results[0].geometry.location;
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map
                });
                 
                 
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                return function () {
                    console.log(i);
                    console.log(locations)
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
            };
         })(i));
    }
```

```css
#map{
   height:400px;
   width:500px; 
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>

<
```